# Resetting Application Class in android

Tags: android

I have an application class named applicationGlobal with many objects like strings, integers. I want to set all of them to their defaults at certain point. Here is my application global class:

```
public class appliationGlobal extends Application {
private String auth_token = "";
private String userID = "";
private String groupID = "";
private String firstVisit = "";
private String activeSubscription = "";
private int stateSelection = 1;
private int clickUserId = 8;
private String groupType = "";
private String currentLoggedUserId = "";
private String checkIn_Id = "";
private String initial_state = "";
private String finial_state = "";
private String[] userIds = new String[8];
private String checkin_status = "insert";
private ArrayList<String> lstfeeling;
private String userProfile = null;
private boolean[] badgeCheck = new boolean[8];
SharedPreferences pref;
private String messageCounts[] = new String[8];
private String messageprofilecount = "0";

public String getMessageprofilecount() {
    return messageprofilecount;
}

public void setMessageprofilecount(String messageprofilecount) {
    this.messageprofilecount = messageprofilecount;
}

private Boolean checkcount = false;

public Boolean getCheckcount() {
    return checkcount;
}

public void setCheckcount(Boolean checkcount) {
    this.checkcount = checkcount;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLstfeeling() {
    return lstfeeling;
}

public void setLstfeeling(ArrayList<String> lstfeeling) {
    this.lstfeeling = lstfeeling;
}

public String getCheckIn_Id() {
    return checkIn_Id;
}

public void setCheckIn_Id(String checkIn_Id) {
    this.checkIn_Id = checkIn_Id;
}

public String getInitial_state() {
    return initial_state;
}

public void setInitial_state(String initial_state) {
    this.initial_state = initial_state;
}

public String getFinial_state() {
    return finial_state;
}

public void setFinial_state(String finial_state) {
    this.finial_state = finial_state;
}

public String getCheckin_status() {
    return checkin_status;
}

public void setCheckin_status(String checkin_status) {
    this.checkin_status = checkin_status;
}

public int getStateSelection() {
    return stateSelection;
}

public void setStateSelection(int stateSelection) {
    this.stateSelection = stateSelection;
}

ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();

public String getAuth_token() {
    return auth_token;
}

public void setAuth_token(String auth_token) {
    this.auth_token = auth_token;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getGroupID() {
    return groupID;
}

public void setGroupID(String groupID) {
    this.groupID = groupID;
}

public String getFirstVisit() {
    return firstVisit;
}

public void setFirstVisit(String firstVisit) {
    this.firstVisit = firstVisit;
}

public String getActiveSubscription() {
    return activeSubscription;
}

public void setActiveSubscription(String activeSubscription) {
    this.activeSubscription = activeSubscription;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGroupNames() {
    return groupNames;
}

public void setGroupNames(ArrayList<String> groupNames) {
    this.groupNames = groupNames;
}

public String getGroupType() {
    return groupType;
}

public void setGroupType(String groupType) {
    this.groupType = groupType;
}

public String getUserProfile() {
    return userProfile;
}

public void setUserProfile(String userProfile) {
    this.userProfile = userProfile;
}

public String getCurrentLoggedUserId() {
    return currentLoggedUserId;
}

public void setCurrentLoggedUserId(String currentLoggedUserId) {
    this.currentLoggedUserId = currentLoggedUserId;
}

public boolean getBadgeCheck(int x) {
    return badgeCheck[x];
}

public void setBadgeCheck(int x, boolean badgeC) {
    this.badgeCheck[x] = badgeC;
}

public String getUserIds(int x) {
    return userIds[x];
}

public void setUserIds(int x, String userI) {
    this.userIds[x] = userI;
}

public int getIdNumber(String x) {
    for (int trp = 0; trp < 8; trp++) {
        if (userIds[trp].equals(x))
            return trp;
    }
    return 0;
}

public String getMessageCounts(int x) {
    return messageCounts[x];
}

public void setMessageCounts(int x, String messageC) {
    this.messageCounts[x] = messageC;
}

public int getClickUserId() {
    return clickUserId;
}

public void setClickUserId(int x) {
    this.clickUserId = x;
}
}
```

Is it possible to set all of them to their default value by some in-built function?

Comment: Set them to their default values by calling a method when you want them to change.

Comment: I know, but isn't there any default function? Its a little pain if there are lots of variables :)

Comment: As far as i know there is no default function that could set user them to default. Sorry.

Comment: Lol no need to sorry. Thanks for replying instead :)